# how can I integrate sails.js with compass?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

first excuse my English, I would like to have all the compilation power of compass in sails, compass is able to watch many directories and compile the files that doesn't begin with _, and it creates he same directory structure for the compiled files. how can I do this with grunt or how can I add compass to grunt and let compass compile the files, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sails.js uses grunt for automatic / manual task running.
If you need to simplify or automate compass tasks, use [grunt-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-compass) .

**Technical Details**

- Create a new file tasks/config/compass.js with contents similar to below

  ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
      grunt.config.set('compass', {
          src: 'assets/scss/partials',
          dest: 'assets/css/partials'
      });
      grunt.loadTasks('grunt-compass/tasks');

    };
  ```
- Then you should be able to run the tasks using 
  `grunt compass`
- Edit the tasks/watch.js file and add the compass task alongwith linkAssets task etc if you want to run the task on file changes.